# choosing best opencv facial detector

Tags: opencv

I am very new to opencv and able to install it so far. I want to compare a face with other different faces available in library and to find out the closest match. I have tried different features but couldn't find the closer answer.

Any suggestion to choose a detector.

dimensions of input image and images in library are same.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

i think, you want face *recognition* (who is it?), not *detection* (is it a face?).

[look here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html) for what opencv has to offer there